Google Cloud run couldn't connect to postgre after deployment (node.js & prisma)
I have built a backend service for my app using node.js with prisma, and i built images with docker to send it into artifact regiestery in google cloud. But after deploying the image, then i tried post (https://iXXam-connect-api-zsXXXcuetq-et.a.run.app/auth/register) on postman it always says
{
    "message": "\nInvalid `prisma.users.create()` invocation in\n/app/src/modules/authentication/auth.repository.js:11:35\n\n   8 const createUserDto = CreateUserDTO.fromRequest(data);\n   9 createUserDto.validate();\n  10 \n→ 11 return await prisma.users.create(\nCan't reach database server at `3x.3x.2x8.1x7:5432`\n\nPlease make sure your database server is running at `3x.3x.2x8.1x7:5432`."
}

but i try running it locally and it can run on desired db with the ip connection. it only doesnt work with the deployed url in cloud run. I tried almost everything, it does zero thing to my problem... T-T im crying with a big
((These below are my detailed files that might help))

this is my Dockerfile :

# Use the official Node.js image from the Docker Hub
FROM node:18

# Create and change to the app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . ./

# Expose the port that the app runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Define the command to run the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]



This is my docker-compose.yaml :

version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ihXXmConnect-api
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres-db
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  pgdata:



this is my server.js :

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const authController = require('./modules/authentication/auth.controller');
const voiceController = require('./modules/voice/voice.controller');
const placesController = require('./modules/places/places.controller');

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

// Create the Express application
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Middleware for parsing JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Middleware for parsing URL-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Serve static files from the uploads directory
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

// Endpoint routes
app.use('/auth', authController);
app.use('/voices', voiceController);
app.use('/places', placesController);

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});



this is my .env :

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:****@3x.3x.2x8.1x7:5432/ihramdb?schema=public"

JWT_SECRET=bangkit
JWT_EXPIRE=30d
APP_PORT=8080
APP_STAGE=development
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/
PORT=8080
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=******
NODE_ENV=development


this is my schema.prisma :

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model users {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  role      Int
}


model voices {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  filePath  String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model places {
  id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  place      String
  alamat     String
  rating     Float
  jarakMekkah Float
}

i tried deploying via adding the repo to the google cloud first but i got the error that it couldnt listen to the desired port.. because it has to be a "--platform linux/amd64" line that google cloud doesnt recognize when running gcloud run deploy

You said

but i try running it locally and it can run on desired db with the ip connection

So that works because it is locally, so the applications and the database communicate as they are on the same network.
But when you deploy it to Cloud Run, the Cloud Run needs to be able to access the database at the specified IP address.
Maybe you can try pinging the IP from the Cloud Run or anything network related to see if you can actually reach the Ip address.

i tried pinging the ip and it is connected/pinging... thing is i have connected with the db with the ip locally, it workds, but somehow in google cloud it doesnt..
